# How to specify a parameters for Gamma distribution?

Tags: r, self-study, gamma-distribution, compound-distributions

I have a task: A frequency claim distribution, $K$ is a compound Poisson-Gamma distribution. The mean of the Poisson distribution is gamma distributed with mean equal to 1 and variation equal 2. Find the probability $P(K=1)$?

My attempt is.

Let's denote $K|\Lambda \sim Pois(\Lambda)$, $\Lambda \sim \Gamma(a, b)$ and $E(\Lambda)=1$ and $Var(\Lambda)=2$ then $a=b=1/2$.

The compound Poisson-Gamma distribution is a Negative-Binomial distibution and one can compute
$$P(K=k)=C^k_{a+k-1}·p^a·(1-p)^k$$ where $p=\frac{b}{b+1}$.

In case $K=1$: $$P(K=1)=a·p^a·(1-p)=\frac 12 \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{1/2} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \approx 0.19245.$$
I would like to use the [nlirms](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlirms/nlirms.pdf) package to repeate the calculation:

```
library(nlirms)
dPGA(k=1, mu=1, sigma=sqrt(2))
# [1] 0.2437764
```

**Edit.** One can see that answers are different. The possible reason that dPGA() is a disribution but not probabilty function.

**Quetion.** How to specify the `mu` and `sigma` parameters?